# Dynamically order columns MS Access subform

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to re-order columns in MS Access form on click of the button.

1. If **Column Sequence1** button clicked order should be Col1, Col2, Col3
2. If **Column Sequence2** button clicked order should be Col3, Col2, Col1
3. If **Column Sequence3** button clicked order should be Col2, Col1, Col3

Please refer below screenshot for the reference

[image]

I tried, but column order is changing only when it is saved manually in the mainform or Subform. Please help on VBA script

Comment: Took me about 5 sec to find this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.columnorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming two columns (instead of your two, but easy to extend); you can change these properties:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
  With Me.MyTbl_subform.Controls
       !Col1_Label.Caption = "ColA" ' Column Heading on the form
       !Col2_Label.Caption = "ColB"
       !Col1.ControlSource = "ColA" ' Column name from Table/Query in RecordSource
       !Col2.ControlSource = "ColB"
  End With
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  With Me.MyTbl_subform.Controls
       !Col1_Label.Caption = "ColB"
       !Col2_Label.Caption = "ColA"
       !Col1.ControlSource = "ColB"
       !Col2.ControlSource = "ColA"
  End With

End Sub
```

Col1_Label, Col2_Label, Col1, and Col2 are the control names on the subform; ColA and ColB are the column names on the subform's source table/query.

Comment: Probably because is it much simpler to reorder the ColumnOrders: [TextBox.ColumnOrder property (Access)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.textbox.columnorder?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361). It will also preserve _events_ of those textboxes.